# Avoiding or catch Error read ECONNRESET at TCP.onStreamRead

Tags: node.js

I'm using sockets to communicate with my clients.
Now I'm getting 10 times a day an error:

```sh
{
  Error: read ECONNRESET at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:111:27) errno: 'ECONNRESET',
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}
```

I add an event on the server:

```js
server.on('error', (err,socket) => {
  try {
    console.log('Server error:', err,socket)
    socket.end('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\n\r\n');
    socket.Close(); 
  } catch(e){}
});

server.on('clientError', (err, socket) => {
  try{
    if (err.code === 'ECONNRESET' || !socket.writable) {
      console.error('__ECONNRESET',err,socket);
      return;
    }
    socket.end('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\n\r\n');
  } catch(e){}
});
```

but the server process restarts.

I'm on `node` version v15.3.0, if that matters.

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was wrong? I'm getting a similar error.